# How to connect REACT frontend hosted on Heroku to AWS (Spring-Boot) backend?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, heroku

I have a Spring-boot backend deployment on AWS EC2 (using EBS).My REACT frontend is on Heroku
and can't connect to the backend. I have manually added CORs on Spring APP, configured security group, but it still doesn't work. I can connect to bacend from localhost:3000 just fine.

The same problem doesn't happen if I deploy the backend on herku and connect frontend from Heroku/Firebase. This seems to happen only with AWS backend.

1. How do I connect Heroku frontend with AWS backend ?
2. Can we solve this by deploying REACt on AWS?

My security group config.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udB5h.png)

Comment: It is not clear, how you are configuring your backend's DNS and making it available/discoverable for front end.  Are there are any loadbalancer or static ip, eni/eip associated with backend and any friendly dns cname which maps to the backend which is configured for front end.

Comment: Why on earth would you host your front-end on Heroku if you're already using AWS? Just drop it into an S3 bucket, flip on the web hosting option or configure a CDN, and you're done. Heroku isn't meant for static sites.

Comment: @in4976 I have a public IPV4 DNS and I can connect to it with Postman or localhost:3000. But, Once I try to deploy on Heroku it doesn't work. I'm not sure about the static IP or how to add one.

Comment: Since the ipv4 dns is accessible through postman, believe nacl and routetable for ec2 in your vpc is reachable and communicates back.. are there any special rules which are part of your nacl setup?